# how to display pin image on image using x and y coordinates

Tags: android, imageview

In my project I want to display pin image on map image using x and y coordinates.The following image is getting from the web service with particular height and width.

[image]

And also getting the array of **x** and **y** coordinates from the web service.By using these coordinates I want to display the pin images on that map image like following image.

[image]

So that's why i have designed the xml like the following

```
<ScrollView 
    android:background="#b1cdc4"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So that my question is how to set map image programatically to imageview with particular height and width.And in that map image how to display pin images using x and y coordinates.So please suggest me how to do this. Thanks to all in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you to subclass [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and override then [onDraw()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) method..
You can than draw directly to the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). Like this..

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas); //this will draw the image
    drawPins(canvas); // now take the canvas and draw your pins
}
```

Regarding drawing to the canvas you can find a lot of tutorials on the web, or even here on SO.